# What can make unmounted volumes SHA512 hashes differ while mounted volumes content SHA512 hashes are identical?

Tags: hashing, forensics

I am trying to configure Raspberry Pi OS to be read-only.

In theory, both `/` and `/boot` are read-only. That being said, I am experiencing a strange discrepancy and can’t figure out what is happening.

I create clones of `/boot` using `dd` before and after discrepancy occurs to find what changed.

Using `diff`, apparently nothing has… puzzled.

```
$ sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img
SHA512(/Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img)= ce87ce4b05149a85d286b62528776c010ddae4d25c5eaa1e79275be118125d66396645587f084073cbf87e36d6627f8d96ad02688a20ede898152df95fa88686

$ sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed.img
SHA512(/Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed.img)= 62e9727727c2307ef452a8f029617c7e7369c8b9c797027d8088a53ed0ada988dbfc128b389d35a729cc8fb00d4214fa4c2f1decd285e5e0f33553a8b63a29da

$ diff /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img  /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed.img
Binary files /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img and /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed.img differ
```

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img

$ mount -o ro -t msdos /dev/disk2 ~/Desktop/boot-clean

$ sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean
SHA512(/Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean)= 27d3b8c676879d944e148384e78dc6b77fc2d5a67c195bdbedf8157a57ff6e7f317e53e10fe2e030d154d8102f55710ec28a701582da04246edc541e600e12a3

$ hdiutil attach -nomount /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed.img

$ mount -o ro -t msdos /dev/disk3 ~/Desktop/boot-changed

$ SHA512(/Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed)= 27d3b8c676879d944e148384e78dc6b77fc2d5a67c195bdbedf8157a57ff6e7f317e53e10fe2e030d154d8102f55710ec28a701582da04246edc541e600e12a3

$ diff --brief --recursive /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-changed
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot replicate your actions. Also, the output of the last diff is missing.

Comment: Hey @kelalaka, I was hoping someone would have experienced something similar. I believe the last diff has no output because content of folders is identical.

Comment: right, if the diff returns 0 then they are the same. Note that this is better to be asked at superUser, however, the verification is hard.